# Setting ListView Height based on items gives extra space at the end in Android Nougat device

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, listviewitem

I am using the below function to set the height of my ListView dynamically based on the number of items in the ListView.

```
public boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView, String select) {
    MyListAdapter adapter = (MyListAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter != null) {
        int numberOfItems = adapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = adapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            float px = 300 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Get padding
        int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding; // +50
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above function works well on the device with there screen density mentioned below along with the OS.

> Moto E3 Power (Android 6.0, 720 x 1280 pixels, 5.0 inch screen).
>
> Lenovo A6010 (Android 5.0.2, 720 x 1280 pixels, 5.0 inch screen).
>
> Samsung Tablet SM T113 (Android 4.4.4, 600 x 1024 pixels, 7.0 inch
>   screen).

[image: Screen Shot of devices where the function works well]

But, When I run the same on the Device with Android Nougat (7.0, 7.1.1), I get empty spaces below the last item of my ListView. That is, the height is set more than required.

The below screen shot explains what I am facing. 
[image]
The Devices which are giving this issue are listed below:-

> Moto E4 Plus (Android - 7.1.1, 720 x 1280 pixels, 5.5 inch screen).
>
> Moto E5 Plus (Android - 7.0, 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inch screen).

Below is my XMl declaration of the ListView.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
        android:divider="@color/transparent" />
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue I am facing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to give listview in xml file height as "wrap_content".

Comment: @DemoMail I have used that, but no change. Still the issue remains the same

Comment: First open your list activity in device, then, in android studio, go to tools->android->layout inspector. it will capture the screen and show it in the android studio. just check there, which view is capturing the space, either your listview or the single item of listview.

Comment: @DemoMail I have check as you directed. Its the Listview which is capturing the space and not the listView item. Any Suggestion from you kind end now to resolve the issue.

Comment: why you are giving dynamic height to listview items? if you remove the dynamic height then i think it will work

Comment: Hi, could you solve your problem?

Comment: @GabrielIntriago Yes I was able to solve it.

Comment: Please, can you post the answer describing how you solved it?. You would help me a lot to solve a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielIntriago Yes Sure, Just give me 2-3 hrs, in between some work, shall put the solution for the same.

Comment: @GabrielIntriago Posted the answer, Hope it will help you. Sorry for posting it late.

Answer (score 2):

I Got the solution to the issue I was facing.

For Me the solution lied in the item list of the adapter i was using for my List View.

I was using `LinearLayout` with `weight` and to the widgets inside the LinearLayout I was giving `weightsum` along with some `margin` to the `Views`.
Now as the entire view was divided by weightsum views the additional margin was creating those white space at the bottom of my `ListView` Attributes as shown in the question posted. I replace the `LinearLayout` with the `RelativeLayout` and removed the `weight` attribute from the `ViewGroup` and `weightSum` attributes from my `View`.

And it has worked for me.

For those who are facing the same issue I am posting the xml file below for the reference:

My Old item_list.xml file Used for ListView item UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp5"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/iv_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox_menu_detail_item"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.3"
        android:text="dsfdsfds"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="dsfdsfds"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp15" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_add_sub"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_subtract"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp25"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
            android:src="@drawable/minus" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_count"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp25"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_add"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp25"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My `list_item.xml` file where I replaced the `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and without using the `weight` and `weightSum` Attributes:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_background_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/iv_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5"
        style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
        android:textColor="@color/app_text_color_primary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_checkbox"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/liLayRightPanel"
        android:text="dsfdsfd"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
        android:textColor="@color/app_text_color_primary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp15" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liLayRightPanel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsfdsfd"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/app_text_color_primary"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp15" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layout_add_sub"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_subtract"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_theme_bkgnd"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                android:src="@drawable/minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/app_text_color_primary" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_theme_bkgnd"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                android:src="@drawable/add" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope My Answer can help those who are facing the same issue...